# Get info about all media objects in one query from Facebook Instagram API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

I'm trying to get all avalible info about my media data on Instagram business profile. Problem is that when i try to do that in signe query:

```
instagram_business_account_id/media?fields=media_type,insights.metric(impressions,carousel_album_saved,engagement,video_views)
```

I'm getting followin error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Can not show video views count for non video media",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

Is there any way I can filter response by media_type or any other way to get all data in one request or to split them in small ones, so I don't need to make API call for every media object file?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution, which is incredibly wasteful, is to filter on the media type after the request to /media. Use the cursors to build the full list then post process.

Comment: Can you post how to filter by media_type?